# How to get uppercase section name in beamer with \insertsection?

Tags: beamer

I want to have a beamer presentation with a slide with the section name.

This does what I need, as a MWE, and it works:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}
        \centering\Huge
        --- \insertsection\ ---
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{First}
\begin{frame}
    This is a first
\end{frame}

\section{Second}
\begin{frame}
    This is a second
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But I want to show the section name in uppercase, but if I try the following modification, I get tons of errors.

```
\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}
        \centering\Huge
        --- \MakeUppercase{\insertsection} ---
    \end{frame}
}
```

These are the first lines of the errors:

```
Undefined control sequence. \section{First}
Argument of \beamerx@\hyperlink has an extra }. \section{First}
Paragraph ended before \beamerx@\hyperlink was complete. \section{First}
Undefined control sequence. \section{First}
Use of \beamer@foundspec doesn't match its definition. \section{First}
Undefined control sequence. \section{First}
Undefined control sequence. \section{First}
Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }. \section{First}
--- cut ---
```

Any tips how to get the uppercase here? I'm really lost...

---

### Edit

Everthing ok after updating to v3.50.

Comment: Actually `\MakeUppercase{\insertsection}` works fine for me. Which version of beamer do you have?

Comment: It says `\def\beamer@version{3.36}`. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @Jader Update! ~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: With v3.50  it works fine.

Comment: Updating to 3.50 solved the problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been fixed and works without problems in v3.50

Comment: Doesn't work for me either...  I'll check the beamer version, as suggested in the comment by @samcarter (you) above...